# What do I need to do to get permission to create file with fopen() in c with VS Code

Tags: c, windows-10, fopen, permission-denied

The following code seems to give me a pointer to the existing file "first.wav" (in a folder on my desktop) but does not allow me to create the new file "second.wav".

```
    FILE *first = fopen("first.wav", "r");  
    if (first == NULL)
    {
        perror ("The following error occurred"); 
        printf( "errno1: %d\n", errno );
        printf("Could not open file.\n");
        return 1;
    }
    FILE *second = fopen("second.wav", "w");  
    if (second == NULL)
    {
        perror ("The following error occurred");
        printf( "errno2: %d\n", errno );
        printf("Could not open file.\n");
        return 1;
    }
```

the error message i get is..
The following error occurred: Permission denied
errno2: 13

I have checked that I'm in the right working directory with _getcwd.
Also tried running VS Code both as an admin and not as admin.

I'm using VS Code 1.73.1 on win10 x64

How do I get permission to write "second.wav" in the current working dir?

Comment: That is an operating system issue, not a C issue, and certainly not a VSCode issue - your chosen text editor has no impact on the runtime behaviour of your code clearly.  If it is permissions related it is _your_ code that must run as admin, not VSCode.  Understand that VS Code is not running your code or providing its execution environment, it is an independent executable.  That said, it is not clear why you would not have write permission in a desktop folder.

Comment: @Clifford I misread the question, thought OP was referring to the first file.

Comment: @Haris  The attributes of the folder may be an issue however.